# What defines a bread as 'artisan'?

Tags: bread

'Artisan' is a term thrown around a lot right now in the bread world.  What defines something as an 'artisan' bread?  Is it a function of the recipe, the technique, or the person?  Note, I'm not talking about just store bought bread here - but books like [Artisan Breads Everyday](http://www.amazon.com/Peter-Reinharts-Artisan-Breads-Every).  So clearly it can't be just a grocery marketing term.  (It could be more generally a marketing term.)

Comment: An extra five dollars per copy of the cookbook plus ten thousand more units sold? It's a buzzword, meant to make the baker feel all authentic and crafty. Even if someone can provide a reasonable definition there is no one who *enforces it*, so publishers and authors use t for their own devices.

Comment: Marketing = Deliberate Confusion

Comment: Artisan is one of the most expensive words in the English language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think everyone agrees that "artisan" gets tossed around as a marketing term that is largely empty or vapid, referring as much to the "old world" images used on the bag than to the bread itself.

However, I think there is an actual "artisan" quality to food, and that it relates to several qualities or ethics of the producer - which you do find in some actual bakeries:

- Develops their own recipes - an artisan baker should be developing recipes that meet their needs. If they don't know enough to do that, then they are just following instructions.
- Tweaks recipes carefully over time to maximize the intended qualities of the bread. An "artisan" producer understands the variables that impact the quality of their product and constantly adjust them to keep the bread quality high, despite changing or variable ingredients.
- Follows the ethic of "Flavor Rules", and flavor is the first priority. Of course they have to be a business-person as well, but recipe changes and enhancements should primarily be made to improve flavor, not reduce cost, improve packability, etc.
- Has a real passion for what they are doing, and holds themselves to the highest standard. Artists are always the most critical of their own work, and are constantly looking for ways to improve.

A home baker may not be an "artist", but when I make "artisan breads" at home (and I think this is what Peter R. is referring to), I do so with an intent to make the bread as good as I possibly can, even if this means baking it tomorrow instead of tonight, or ordering special flours online. I contrast this with my "makin' dinner" baking, where I obviously want it to be good, but am willing to give up some perfection in order to get it done tonight. Neither method is inherently better, but they are undertaken with a different intent and process.

Comment: Accepted because it acknowledges that its largely a marketing term but then defines it in a way consistent with what I was *trying* to ask.  I just really don't care that much about the way it refers to grocery store bread.

Answer (score 1):

Artisan is really a marketing word. There seems to be a couple of scenarios in which it is used:

1. To make the consumer believe they are getting a superior product. Instead of 'white bread' (which is just *so* 1960's, they tell you it's an 'artisan loaf', and they charge 3 or 4 dollars. I ran bakeries for over ten years, and I know how crazy they are for Gross Profit. Normally, chain grocery stores are pushing for 60% profit. We would sell loaves that cost us in the region of 25 cents to produce for over 2 dollars. And to make the consumer feel like they were getting a 'deal', we would say 'artisan' or any other variety of fancy words to dress up our product.
2. Cover the fact that most grocery stores do not hire any people with actual baking skills. Most often, bakers are hired off the street, and they are trained to add a certain amount of water, a bag of premixed flour, and a couple of pounds of yeast, then press 'start' on the mixer. No trouble shooting abilities, no real skills. Even more prevelant over the last number of years: go to the freezer, open a box of 'artisan breads', and bake the prebaked loaf for ten minutes.

I don't want to sound negative, but that is absolutely the way it is (at least here in Canada/North America).

Bottom line is that most often, when you are buying a loaf of bread marketed as 'artisan', it isn't. It is either parbaked (industry term for "partially baked" - ie frozen and needing just a few more minutes to finish the bake), or it is being produced by someone with very little know how.

EDIT

Fair enough that you are not just looking for the grocery strore usage. However, I guess you could easily take this in a broader sense. There is no 'artisan' technique. What these book sellers (and grocery stores) are doing is trying to make you think that they are teaching you 'old world principals' in bread making. That's the point. It's simply a buzz word to try to get you to pay more.

Comment: Is this a bit too cynical? Obviously there are people slapping "artisan" on everything, but there IS a difference between different bakers and bakeries in how they develop, produce, and treat their products. What words would you use to describe those differences? Artisan is clearly not a "regulated" term, but it isn't entirely devoid of meaning, either.

Comment: I expected that there would be folks thinking I was overtly cynical. I agree that there is a difference, but the bulk of people get their baked goods from the types of places I describe. I know full well, as I was involved in it for 15 years. Also, it has been my experience that anyone who creates a product worthy of the label 'artisan' would NEVER use that word. It is such an overused, hyped buzzword they would steer clear. THOSE bakers let their product speak for itself and do not need to use such a word. Call me cynical if you wish...

Comment: So...you're suggesting anybody who uses that word must not have good product....think about that...

Comment: You would be foolish to use that word now. Once the mass marketing people got hold of it, any potential "real" meaning has been destroyed

Comment: @rfusca - The comment above has an almost menacing tone, almost implying that I had not fully thought through what I was saying.  However, it is pretty much EXACTLY what I'm saying. Most of the product being sold as 'artisan' is really fairly crappy (pardon the expression). I was fully trained in 'artisinal' methodology (read - proper scratch baking techniques) - and I can 100 per cent garauntee you that modern 'aritisan' products do not tend to approach these methods. The word is simply there to make you think that they do. Sorry to burst your bubble.

Comment: @rfusca - apologies if I seem to be coming accross as a dick, I really don't mean to. This is actually just a topic that I consider very near and dear to me, as I spent a good part of my life working with many of these 'artisans'. It drove me crazy for many years. So yes, I realize that I am slightly jaded.

Comment: @mrwienerdog - sorry about the menacing tone - you're just implying that some world renowned bakers are crap simply because they chose a particular term.

Comment: No, no, that's not what I mean. Originally I was speaking solely to grocers... and they ARE mostly crap because of the choice of that term. I think if you fuse the my answer and the original comment made after you first posted your question (they add the term to charge more for a book), that it's a fair statement. The world renowned bakers are great - they are just a tad 'charlatan'-ish, that's all. In the cookbook world, the term 'artisan' is used to peddle the books to a certain clientel (housewives? - that's what we used to say in school), and in stores, well, I covered my opinion on that.

Comment: Weinerdog - I'm reminded of the paraphrased saying, "Those who respect the law and like bread should never watch either being made." - I know what it is like to work in an industry that is idealized by the public, but has a more "complex" underbelly. I do respect your experience in the business. I think the thing the OP was getting at is as much about what the word "should" mean, in contrast to what it often means. And sometimes it still means what it should - Peter Reinhart is a legit baker and writer.

Comment: @Sam Ley - thanks for the input, appreciate it. Thank God I'm not involved anymore... New job, new set of mysteries to be debunked. 

Also, it 'mr'wienerdog to you... Hahahahaha!!!! Jusk kidding!

Answer (score -1):

The Term Artisan SHOULD (not saying it is) be used as a term for Scratch Cooking or baking in old world technique. Meaning, none of this "Semi Homecooked" Crap. I consider myself to be an "Artisanal Chef" meaning that IF I can make it myself. I will. period. Just about anything can be "Artisan" and it is a beautiful term, to me it brings up images of beautiful loaves of bread with a thick crust, deliciously mouth watering cheeses, smoked meats, and wonderful jams and sauces. But sadly this term has been watered down, to mean anything made to look "old world style" never mind that it has been produced with bagged mix, or frozen products. If it looks old world it is artisan. BS in my opinion. Go to a farmers market, local bakery, local coffee shop, or local butcher...there you will find the real Artisan products.

Comment: Sounds like a terribly insufficient definition to me. I connect "artisan" with quality, I could do something terrible from scratch and by your definition call it "artisan".

Comment: got my upvote because 'scratch in old world technique' bout sums it up. part that's missing imho is 'by someone trained in old world technique'. Especially if addressed Meister (and die Papiere to show it)